# Should new UPVC windows let water into the lower frame from just heavy rain

Tags: windows, rain, weep-hole

[image]
[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

We just got new UPVC windows and found water in the frame after heavy rain the three back windows you can open up. So this is the norm and it should drain away or dry out. If I push the water to what I take as weep holes I can see it leave the bottom of the frame outside onto the window ledge. So heavy rain actually comes through to the frame below the window even when it looks like a sealed outside.

Would someone clear this up for me who knows what they are talking about. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If the outside windows are closed and water comes in, then something is not right.  Water/rain should flow down the outside and out the weeping holes.  Should only have water inside if there is condensation(humid air on cold surface) on the inside of the windows.

Comment: Sorry added a picture now. It doesn’t come onto the actual bedroom windowsill in the room just between the frame when you open the windows.

Comment: Yeah, houses aren't boats. They aren't waterproof. They _shed_ water. Heavy enough rain will overwhelm almost any window.

Comment: Our last windows were 30 years old and I can’t remember ever seeing water like that in the frame. I just thought the windows would be sealed and water would not get in.

Comment: no, it should not be inside regardless, where does it comes from, the top ?

Comment: Couldn’t tell you I’d guess it’s just bypassing the outer black rubber seal. It does drain away through what I take is weep holes.

Comment: Heavy rain.  Was it coming down at an angle or more sideways straight at the window?

Comment: why is the black rubber seal broken at the corner on left side

Comment: It was hitting the back window, so water was running down the window outside for a few hours.

Comment: I added a picture of the corner but all the windows look similar.

Comment: Does that window open inwards, or is it a sash?

Comment: It’s one of them open completely in and can tilt open as well so it’s open for air at the top.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood that windows are not 100% watertight, but the design allows for this with the weep holes as you've seen. BUT, that seal looks might chewed up at the corner there... 

Under pressure from heavy rain, it's not going to take much of a flaw in any part of the seal to leak earlier than is ideal. And in a few years once the weep holes are blocked with debris, you might have a bigger problem...